# Picasso library refresh images in interval

Tags: android, imageview, reload, android-image, picasso

Does Picasso provide some mechanism to auto refresh images every n seconds/minutes.
Need this for some cctv images and stats images that I want to be auto refreshed every n seconds/minutes.

Furthermore in some cases it's for one image on screen and sometimes I need to do that for gridview with images (every image should be refreshed every 30 seconds or so)

Comment: Can't find anything resembling your question in Github, but you might ask the developer http://twitter.com/lucasratmundo

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `Picasso.with(context).invalidate();`

It will reload all images. I don't think, that picasso provide any another solutions